# How do I p/invoke clock_gettime on .NET?

Tags: .net, linux, f#, mono, pinvoke

Currently I have this F# code to get the highest resolution, linear timestamps I can manage -

```
/// The linux representation of time.
type internal timeval =
    struct
        val tv_sec : int
        val tv_usec : int
        end

/// Query the linux gettimeofday system call.
[<DllImport("libc")>]
extern void private gettimeofday (timeval&, int64)

/// Get a time stamp at the highest-available resolution on linux.
let internal getTimeStampInternal () =
    let mutable t = timeval ()
    gettimeofday(&t, -1L);
    int64 t.tv_sec * 1000000L + int64 t.tv_usec
```

Unfortunately, this value is not linear due to things like leap-year and system time changes.

I've read that the `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` variant of the `clock_gettime` linux function will yield more linear, and possibly higher-resolution results (and I'm hoping this also applies to the Mac).

Problem is that while I did rather a bit of googling, I couldn't find out how to invoke it from .NET, such as using the `[<DllImport>]` attribute as used with gettimeofday above.

How would I do this, and if I can't do this with a simple DllImport, what would be a work-around?

Comment: Are you trying to convert DateTime to Linux Time?

Comment: No sir :) In fact, wall clock time is completely immaterial to what I'm really trying to acheive. I just want a linear, high resolution way to create timestamps on linux so that my game engine ultimately has a cross-platform way of observing the order in which past events (such as entity creation) took place.

Comment: @Bryan : What's wrong with `System.Diagnostics.StopWatch`?

Comment: On .NET, Stopwatch.GetTimestamp does not have nearly the resolution I need, so I rather doubt I can trust its resolution on Linux as well. I also searched the mono code base to look for its implementation here - https://github.com/mono/mono - but cannot find one.

Comment: Nevermind, I found it. Looks like Mono on Linux does actually use clock_gettime for Stopwatch.GetTimestamp through the mono_100ns_ticks function - which actually seems sufficient! See the code here - https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/9e396e4022a4eefbcdeeae1d86c03afbf04043b7/mono/utils/mono-time.c#L125-L142

Comment: @BryanEdds : It has better than 100ns resolution on Windows, I'm not sure where you got the impression that it doesn't...

Comment: Out of interest why can't you just do `extern int clock_gettime ....`

Comment: I could try that if I knew what the name of the DllImport'ed dll was. Do you know?

Comment: @BryanEdds - I am pretty sure it is in libc